# SSL without a certificate

Tags: codeigniter, ssl

I am developing a backend section for a company where they need as much security as possible because they will put sensible information in it.

They asked me to add SSL, which I added(the website is coded in codeigniter) but I don't know if a SSL certificate is really needed.

Having in mind that this website will only be accesible by a set of two different IPs, the two offices they have I don't think getting a certificate would be needed. Am I right?

Edit 24 Feb:
The data has the information of projects, list of clients so it is sensitive.

So I think I will go with a self signed ssl.

Thank you all

Comment: If the _cost_ of getting a certificate is your main concern(?) – then use a self-signed one. (People using this site will only have to accept it in their browser once.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few other issues you should keep in mind, in addition to those who have previously answered:

1. Will the users of this site be connecting and transferring this sensitive information over a wireless connection at any point in time? If this is the case, then yes, you need SSL.
2. HTTPS is not such a burden on server resources as it once was. Especially with a site only being used by a limited number of users at defined locations, you should certainly be able to provide for the maximum number of users.
3. If this is a private site, and cost is an issue, go with a self-signed certificate. The OpenSSL toolkit is your best bet for this. Numerous guides for setting up self-signed certificates with OpenSSL are available.
4. Are there legal issues involved with this sensitive data? If you are transmitting customer information in a client database with phone numbers, postal addresses, email addresses, login information - or even more seriously, credit card numbers - then you need SSL. Ask yourself if you would trust a company who transmitted this same information of yours without SSL.
5. If the client asked for it and is paying for it, this isn't an undue burden on you as a developer, and as a developer you really never want to be in the position where you're arguing for less security. If there's a problem later, it comes back to bite you. Cover your rear end.
6. Combine this with IP restricted access. If you can, do that at the Apache configuration level. If not, then do it with a .htaccess. Why at the Apache level? Again, that covers your rear end in case you forget to put the restrictions in a .htaccess, or in case someone else comes in and removes them by accident.

If there's even a question about it, use SSL.

Answer (score 0):

SSL certificate is needed because somebody could read the request content on the way to your server. You can't add https to the web page without certificate (check if you have **https** protocol in the browser page address).

In developing stage you can generate SSL certificate by yourself (use openssl) there is no need to buy valid one. There will be warning in the browser that the certificate is not signed by any authority, but I don't think that is big problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to protect clinet-server communication (http request/response headers and data) from being overheard, then you need to install SSL on your sever, and use https protocol. This is useful when you want to hide i.e. user credentials.

If it is just about allow/disable access for mentioned ip addresses, than it is enough to limit it in http server configuration (usually .htaccess).

Please keep in mind, that https requests requires more server/client resources (CPU), so it should not be used if not necessary.